# In Futsal, can a goalkeeper score with a drop kick (i.e. released from hands)?

Tags: rules, scoring, goalkeeper, futsal

The question is about Futsal.

Consider the following situation:

1. The goalkeeper holds the ball in his hands after the opposing team's attack. The ball has not left the field so it is not a goal clearance.
2. The goalkeeper releases the ball and then kicks it.
3. The ball hits the post of opposing team's goal and goes in, touching neither the field nor any player.

Will it count?

What if we change the first statement (1.) to be a goal clearance instead.

Will it still count, or will it be an indirect free kick since the goalkeeper needs to throw the ball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ball in Play**
Yes - The goalkeeper may score a goal with his feet from directly inside the goalkeeper’s penalty area when holding a ball in play.

> Law 10 The Method of Scoring
>   ...
>   A goal is disallowed if the goalkeeper of the attacking team throws or hits the
>   ball intentionally with his hand or arm from inside his own penalty area and
>   is the last player to touch or play the ball. *(Page 37)*

**Goal Clearance**
No - A goal may not be scored directly from a goal clearance.

> Law 16 The Goal Clearance
>   ...
>   A goal may not be scored directly from a goal clearance. *(Page 57)*

*Infringements and sanctions*

> If the goalkeeper takes the goal clearance with his foot, the referees will issue
>   a warning and order him to take it with his hand, but the four-second count
>   continues from where it was stopped once the goalkeeper is ready to retake it. *(Page 152)*
>
> If the ball is not thrown directly out of the penalty area from a goal clearance:
>   • the clearance is retaken, but the four-second count is not reset and
>   continues once the goalkeeper is ready to retake it. *(Page 57)*
>
> If the goal clearance is not taken within four seconds:
>   • an indirect free kick is awarded to the opposing team, to be taken from the
>   penalty area line at the place nearest to where the infringement occurred. *(Page 58)*

[FIFA - FUTSAL Laws of the Game 2014/15](http://areferee.com/images/2014_15FutsalLawsoftheGame.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

Also during general play, the goalkeeper is allowed to drop kick the ball and score directly on the opposing net. If the keeper has saved the ball during play and drop kicks it they can score and it counts. If it goes out and it's a restart then the keeper can only release it from their hands so no they can't directly score from that.